# Transforming a second order PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Consider the inhomogeneous PDE 
$$2u_{xx}-u_{xy}-u_{yy}=(x+y)\exp(2y^2+xy-x^2).$$
Using the transformation 
$$m=-x+2y \ \ \  \ \ \text{and} \ \ \ \ \ n=x+y,$$
my goal is to transform this PDE into the form 
$$u_{mn}=aF(m,n).$$
I think this problem will use the chain rule a lot.  From other problems I did before, I am pretty sure I have to start with the fact that 
$$\frac{\partial ^2u}{\partial x^2}=\frac{\partial }{\partial m}\left [ \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \right ]\frac{\partial m}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial }{\partial n}\left [\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}  \right ]\frac{\partial n}{\partial x}.$$However, I'm a little confused.  I don't really know what to do with the function 
$$F(x,y) = (x+y)\exp(2y^2+xy-x^2).$$
Since I am very new to PDEs, I am sure that with time this stuff will become very easy.  But as of now, I can't seem to pinpoint a specific method that will help me solve these problems.  Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $u_{mn}=-\frac 19 n e^{mn}$

Comment: I made an error, sorry!

Comment: @Cesareo How did you come up with this?

Comment: Just applying the chain rule.

Comment: @Cesareo Would you mind writing it down in the answer section so I can give you the upvote and correct answer check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as

$$
m = -x+2y\\
n = x+y
$$

we have

$$
(x+y)e^{2y^2+x y - x^2} = ne^{nm}
$$

and using the chain rule

$$
u_x = u_m m_x + u_n n_x = -u_m+u_n\\
u_y = u_m m_y + u_n n_y = 2u_m+u_n\\
u_{xy} = (-u_m+u_n)_m m_y+ (-u_m+u_n)_n n_y = -2u_{mm}+2u_{nm}+u_{nn}
$$

etc.

After that we obtain $2u_{xx}-u_{xy}-u_{yy} \equiv -9 u_{nm}$ and finally

$$
u_{nm}= -\frac n9 e^{nm}
$$